# Including header file defined by macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, include, c-preprocessor

I need to provide configuration file, which will describe which STL header files to include. I have found that usually it is done by defining a lot of HAVE_XXX_HEADER macros. I wonder if there's something wrong with explicitly providing header name in a macro. Then instead of testing each variant:

```
#if defined(HAVE_TR1_UNORDERED_MAP_HEADER)
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
#elseif (...)
#endif
```

you could simply have:

```
#define UNORDERED_MAP_HEADER <tr1/unordered_map>
(...)
#include UNORDERED_MAP_HEADER
```

which in addition brings flexibility, since header name is not hard coded inside configured file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible and legal in C99, cf ISO 9899:1999 §6.10.2 example 2. A similar example can also be found in the [(draft) C++ standard](http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/cpp.html), 16.2 bullet 8.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can do that. You can also use function macros; for example, I use this in my projects because gcc places TR1 headers in a subdirectory:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  define TR1_HEADER(header) <tr1/header>
#else
#  define TR1_HEADER(header) <header>
#endif

#include TR1_HEADER(unordered_map)
#include TR1_HEADER(memory)
#include TR1_HEADER(functional)
// etc.

#undef TR1_HEADER
```

I have tested this on gcc and MSVC 2008. Other compilers may require other hacks, although in this particular case gcc is not strictly compliant while MSVC is, so it *should* work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing:

```
#define BBB <stdlib.h>
#include BBB
```

And it compiles fine, using MSVS 2005. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that showing it works on a particular compiler doesn't imply it works on every standard-compliant compiler.